# GitLab & nginx: 502

Tags: nginx, debian, ruby, gitlab

I've installed GitLab, following the given official instruction, but I'm getting 502 error when trying to use it.
Nginx log entry:

```
 *30 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.27.118.xx, server: gitlab.somehost.net, request: "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket:/users/sign_in", host: "gitlab.somehost.net"
```

As I remember from the previous GitLab installation experience, the error cause is that GitLab is initializing at the first user access, and nginx thinks, that it's timeout, so the solution is increasing some timeout value. The problem is I didn't remember **which** timeout I should increase (this solved the error for me with the previous installation), and Google doesn't help me.

Comment: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1527

See the reply by Chacham15

Comment: @Cocoabean I don't have unicorn.rb file in config directory. Update: The "puma" is now used in the GitLab, not the Unicorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing RAM solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1527#issuecomment-12313207 mentions it should be changed in unicorn.rb

Comment: Puma is used instead of unicorn in the GitLab.

Comment: We switched back to Unicorn some time ago.

Comment: is it possible that someone fixes those installation bugs or are they simply ignored? I´m struggeling around for days now to get this piece of ... working